# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when adding response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I add the following line `res.status(201).json({ email });` I get the error message `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. What can I do to fix this problem.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
module.exports.signup_post = (req, res ) => {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, password } = req.body;
 
    handleErrorSignup(firstname.trim(), lastname.trim(), email.trim(), password.trim())
        .then( async (errors) => {

            if(errors.firstname === '' && errors.lastname === '' && errors.email === '' && errors.password === '') {
                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync('password', 10);
                try {
                    await db.none('INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)', [firstname, lastname, email, hash]);
                    const token = createToken(email);
                    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
                    res.status(201).json({ email });
                }               
                catch(err) {
                    res.status(400).send('Error, user not created');
                }
                res.redirect('/');
            }
            else {
                res.status(400).json({ errors });
            }
        });        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are sending response from try catch already, so you cannot redirect if you have sent the response already from the earlier parts of your code.

You need to remove this line from your code, or redirect only if response is not already sent in try and catch blocks.

```
try {
  ...
  res.status(201).json({ email });
} catch (err) {
  res.status(400).send('Error, user not created');
}

// Remove below code
res.redirect('/');
```

If you are looking to redirect to your home screen after signup, you need to handle the same in frontend based on the status code or response received for signup from backend.

Comment: Yes. I was meant to remove that. Thank you.